# Vague memory of a movie

Tags: story-identification

In this movie the aliens/robots are more prone to anger than humans are (and/or overly emotional), so whenever someone got too angry as this group of humans tries to escape, they assumed they were an alien and killed them. 
In the end only a guy and a girl survive, but there is only one escape vessel, and it turns out the girl was one of the creatures but she lets the guy escape...

Comment: More details would be helpful. When did you see it? What language was it? Animated or live-action? Ethnicity of the characters? Could it have been an episode of some TV show? Any little detail you can recall, no matter how minor, might be enough to get an "Ah Ha!" from someone.

Comment: [Screamers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114367/) maybe?